Writing and reading API issue objects to/from file
In my program, I am processing issues from jira.
I wanted to add an extra step to save all of my issues in a yaml file and then, when needed read them again. I am storing the original com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue objects in the yaml file (that is why I am using object mappers), since I need them later again as issues.
However, reading these objects seems to be difficult.
Because issue does not seem to have constructors, so remapping is difficult. Does anyone know a workaround or even another file method I can save my issues and read them again?
Saving them as strings or writing my own constructor seems to be my last plan, but I am already processing the issues further a lot and I do not want to change my whole code.
These are my methods for saving the issues and reading them:
private static void saveIssuesToYAMLFile(List<Issue> issues, String yamlPath) throws IOException {

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory().disable(Feature.WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER));

mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());


try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(yamlPath, true))) {

mapper.writeValue(writer, issues);    
    }

 }



private static List<Issue> readIssuesFromYAMLFile(String yamlPath) throws IOException {

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory().disable(Feature.WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER));

mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());



return mapper.readValue(new File(yamlPath), mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, Issue.class));
    }

When I try to read the file I get this error:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)

at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1887)

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DatabindContext.reportBadDefinition(DatabindContext.java:414)

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1375)

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1508)

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:348)

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:185)

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:361)

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:246)

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:30)

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:342)

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4905)

        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3753)

        at com.jira.jirarestclient.issues.Search.readIssuesFromYAMLFile(SearchClient.java:19)

        at com.jira.jirarestclient.issues.Search.readIssuesFromJQL(SearchClient.java:109)

        at com.jira.App.main(App.java:7)

